# How do I create or repair or move my bcd boot file in Windows7?

Tags: windows-7, boot

I used to manipulate the boot.ini manually in my XP days. Now, playing with Win 7, I managed to install it in a way that it created a boot file on a different drive than I usually boot from, so now I don't have dual-boot. To my surprise, I found out there is no boot.ini anymore :) and I have to use bcdedit which is a pretty complex tool. How can I move my boot file to another drive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scott Hanselman [saved me](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/SwitchingMyWindows7BootDiskFromDToCWithBCDBootRatherThanBCDEdit.aspx). Windows 7 has yet another simpler tool called bcdboot to make such kind of tasks easier.